# Size of "vector of objects" Versus "vector of Object pointers"

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm trying to understand how much memory is taken up by using a vector of objects versus vector of pointers. I wrote a small test code:

```
class Test {
public: 
   Test()
   { v.resize(2000); }

private:
    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main() 
{
   std::vector<Test> OCtr;
   std::vector<Test*> PCtr;
   Octr.resize(10);
   PCtr.resize(10, new Test);
   cout << OCtr.size()*sizeof(Test) << endl;
   cout << PCtr.size()*sizeof(Test*) << endl; 
}
```

The output is 120 and 40. I can understand 40 - as it is 10* 4 bytes, but surprised by 120. Is that the real size of the container - OCtr? It looks like sizeof(Test) is not the right way to get complete size of the object.

- Instead of providing a member function inside Test class to sum up memory of all Test data members, is there another to get size of any class object.
- I have read answers on when to use vector of objects versus vector of object pointers. But in a case where I'm creating a container of simple class (no polymorphic behavior), where memory consumption is primary criteria and I can handle deletion of object pointers, which container should I choose?

Comment: OCtr and PCtr take Test as argument.

Comment: thanks for pointing, jagan..done editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof` is a compile-time operator. That is, `sizeof(X)` will be replaced during compilation with a constant number. This means that the `sizeof` an empty `vector<T>` is always the same as the `sizeof` a `vector<T>` with thousands of elements inside of it. Remember, `sizeof` does not do anything during runtime, so the result cannot possibly reflect the current state of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

If you take the size of a vector instance, it will always be the same for a particular system implementation.  In your case it is 12 bytes.  Vectors allocate memory using a default or supplied allocator for the actual storage of their object contents.  This memory is by default from the heap and does not register in the size of the vector object itself.

You can calculate the total amount of memory used for the vector and its data by taking a sizeof the vector type and multiplying by the number of elements, then adding 12 bytes for the vector proper.

Comment: Amardeep - I did not understand "when you say take size of a vector instance". When I do sizeof(Test), I expect atleast 8000 to returned as during Test object creation, I create a integer vector of 2000 elements, which means each Test object should be atleast 8000 bytes..why is Test object size only 12 bytes??

Comment: The std::vector<int> v in class Test is only 12 bytes in size.  The 2000 elements of v take up memory in dynamically allocated memory so are not part of v's own size.

Comment: unless I'm storing polymorphic classes, then I do not see much benefit between storing vector of pointers of vectors of objects. Is that right?

Comment: That is correct.  In non-polymorphic situations, storing the actual object will save a pointer's worth of memory per element and make the design easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: It's not entirely true that the size of any vector will be the same. Some `std::vector` classes provide support for stateful allocators (and this is required for C++11), so if you use a non-default allocator, the size of certain `std::vector` instantiations can be bigger than others. But yes, for any particular instantiation of `std::vector`, it's size will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

120 bytes would be 12 bytes per object, where each object simply stores a vector, so the size of a vector and the size of your class are the same; if I take a guess, I'd guess an int for the size, and int for the capacity, and another pointer to the data, all adding up to 12. That's quite understandable.

Remember that vectors store their data in the heap, so it's not indigenous data, and therefore is not part of the size of the `vector` object which is returned by `sizeof`. Only the size of the pointer that points to that data is counted. So your `v.resize(2000)` doesn't do anything to the size of the object, only to the size of the block of memory on the free store the vector is using.

Comment: but during Test object creation, I create a integer vector of 2000 elements, which means each Test object should be atleast 8000 bytes..why is Test object size only 12 bytes?? thanks

Comment: @cppcoder updated my answer. It's because the vector only stores a _pointer_ to the 2000 elements which really exist on the heap (because they are allocated by `new`), it doesn't store the elements in the object itself.

Comment: @ Seth - Thanks for clarifying..So what happens when I do Test t1; Test t2 = t1; will all 2000 elements be copied to container under t2. Does vector copy constructor or assignment operator take care of all the copying?

Comment: @cppcoder if you are not storing polymorphic objects and your objects are not too expensive to copy around, I recommend storing objects and not pointers to avoid heap allocation for all your objects. If they are expensive to copy around, use pointers so that only the pointers will be copied around.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some things wrong.  First, both `OCtr` and `PCtr` are the same type, which is vector of `Test`.  Not of `Test*` as some of your code suggests.

The expression `PCtr.size()*sizeof(Test*)` is basically meaningless because the things stored in PCtr aren't pointers but whole objects.  Yet you are computing the size of a pointer (which is always the same).

There is no sane way that I know of in C++ to get the total size of an object if it includes dynamic allocation (as vector does).  In other words, you are doing the right thing to multiple `.size()` by `sizeof(Test)` when you have a container of objects, but you need to be more careful when you try to make a container of pointers.